# Vitamin A dose for 7 month old

Tags: infant, health, nutrition

Is there a recommended vitamin A dose for 7 month old babies in some countries? Is it good to have a Vitamin A supplementation at that age? I heard too much vitamin A is not good during pregnancy, but I am not sure how about the first year of the baby.

Comment: we can't know this. Vitamin deficiency depends in a large part on diet. Is he still breastfeeding (in which case does the mother have a vitamin A deficiency?) or is there some underlying medical condition? Why are you worried about vitamin A specifically?

Comment: Asking strangers on the internet medical questions is not a good idea, because we aren't all highly trained medical professionals and are more likely than not to give you the wrong answer. If your baby's doctor recommended or prescribed Vit A, I suggest you address your concerns, including what you've heard, with them. They know your baby, where the baby lives, the causes and effects of Vit A deficiency and the risks and benefits of treating it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the full text of the review by Imdad et al (2017) for the benefits
and side effects of the supplementation.

**This review (and my answer) does not address recommendations for areas
without vitamin A deficiency.**

Note that giving **too much vitamin A can be harmful**
([Hypervitaminosis
A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervitaminosis_A)).

Therefore, like any supplement, vitamin A supplements should generally
only be given if there is a risk of vitamin A deficiency, which
depends on the child's health and nutrition - in particular, vitamin A
deficiency is rare in developed countries.

**Please consult a medical or nutrition professional before deciding to give supplements.**

---

> Is it good to have a Vitamin A supplementation at that age?

Whether it is "good" or not, depends on the specific case.

In areas with significant Vitamin A deficiency, supplementation is beneficial:

> Vitamin A supplementation is associated with a clinically meaningful
> reduction in morbidity and mortality in children.

---

There are general recommendations for some countries, or, more
exactly, areas with vitamin A deficiency (VAD). For example, see:
*World Health Organization (2011) Vitamin A supplementation for
infants and children 6-59 months of age:
https://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/micronutrients/guidelines/vas_6to59_months/en/*

**According to a more recent Cochrane review of 47 studies across 19
countries (Imdad et al., 2017), for 7 month-old children living in
areas with vitamin A deficiency, the recommended vitamin A dose is
100,000 IU every six months.**

*Imdad A, Mayo-Wilson E, Herzer K, Bhutta ZA. Vitamin A supplementation
for preventing morbidity and mortality in children from six months to
five years of age. Cochrane Database of Systematic Reviews 2017, Issue
3. Art. No.: CD008524. DOI: 10.1002/14651858.CD008524.pub3 :
https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD008524.pub3/full*

Again, please see the full text of the review for the benefits and
**side effects (added in bold) of the supplementation**. And, again,
*this review (and my answer) does not address recommendations for
areas without vitamin A deficiency.*

> The World Health Organization (WHO) currently recommends [vitamin A
> supplementation (VAS)] to children between 6 and 59 months of age,
> in a dose of 100,000 IU for children aged 6 to 12 months and a dose
> of 200,000 IU for children aged one to five years, every six months.
> Based on updated results, we suggest continuing this policy for
> children under five years of age in areas at risk of [vitamin A
> deficiency (VAD)]. However, the global policy for universal VAS must
> be revisited for populations where VAD no longer remains a public
> health issue and VAD-associated deaths have markedly declined
> (Stevens 2015). [...]

(from the abstract:)

> A meta-analysis for
> all-cause mortality included 19 trials (1,202,382 children). At
> longest follow-up, there was a 12% observed reduction in the risk of
> all-cause mortality for vitamin A compared with control using a
> fixed-effect model (risk ratio (RR) 0.88, 95% confidence interval
> (CI) 0.83 to 0.93; high-quality evidence). [...] Nine trials
> reported mortality due to diarrhoea and showed a 12% overall
> reduction for VAS (RR 0.88, 95% CI 0.79 to 0.98; 1,098,538
> participants; high-quality evidence). There was no significant
> effect for VAS on mortality due to measles, respiratory disease, and
> meningitis. VAS reduced incidence of diarrhoea (RR 0.85, 95% CI 0.82
> to 0.87; 15 studies; 77,946 participants; low-quality evidence) and
> measles (RR 0.50, 95% CI 0.37 to 0.67; 6 studies; 19,566
> participants; moderate-quality evidence). However, there was no
> significant effect on incidence of respiratory disease or
> hospitalisations due to diarrhoea or pneumonia. **There was an
> increased risk of vomiting within the first 48 hours of VAS (RR
> 1.97, 95% CI 1.44 to 2.69; 4 studies; 10,541 participants;
> moderate-quality evidence).**
>
> Vitamin A supplementation is associated
> with a clinically meaningful reduction in morbidity and mortality in
> children. Therefore, we suggest maintaining the policy of universal
> supplementation for children under five years of age in populations
> at risk of VAD.

---

See also:

Imdad, A., Yakoob, M.Y., Sudfeld, C. et al. Impact of vitamin A
supplementation on infant and childhood mortality. BMC Public Health
11, S20 (2011) doi:10.1186/1471-2458-11-S3-S20 :
https://bmcpublichealth.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2458-11-S3-S20

Map of areas with vitamin A deficiency:
https://bmcpublichealth.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2458-11-S3-S20/figures/13

---

American Academy of Pediatrics ( https://www.aap.org/ ) has no
recommendations on vitamin A supplementation for children that I could
find at the time of writing (compare this to well-known and publicized
recommendations for vitamin D supplementation)

`"vitamin A" site:https://www.aap.org`: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vitamin+A%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.aap.org

`"vitamin D" site:https://www.aap.org`: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vitamin+D%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.aap.org

---

National Institutes of Health (NIH) Office of Dietary Supplements
(ODS) is rather terse regarding vitamin A supplementation in the
United States and other developing countries, see: *NIH ODS, Vitamin
A: Fact Sheet for Health Professionals, October 11, 2019:
https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminA-HealthProfessional/* :

> Frank vitamin A deficiency is rare in the United States. However,
> vitamin A deficiency is common in many developing countries, often
> because residents have limited access to foods containing preformed
> vitamin A from animal-based food sources and they do not commonly
> consume available foods containing beta-carotene due to poverty.
> [...]
>
> In developed countries, clinical vitamin A deficiency is rare in
> infants and occurs only in those with malabsorption
> disorders. However, preterm infants do not have adequate liver stores
> of vitamin A at birth and their plasma concentrations of retinol often
> remain low throughout the first year of life. Preterm infants with
> vitamin A deficiency have an increased risk of eye, chronic lung, and
> gastrointestinal diseases.
> [...]

(In other words, again, vitamin A supplementation should be
case-dependent and under supervision of a medical professional)

> The federal government's 2015-2020 Dietary Guidelines for
> Americans notes that "Nutritional needs should be met primarily from
> foods. ... Foods in nutrient-dense forms contain essential vitamins
> and minerals and also dietary fiber and other naturally occurring
> substances that may have positive health effects. In some cases,
> fortified foods and dietary supplements may be useful in providing one
> or more nutrients that otherwise may be consumed in
> less-than-recommended amounts."

Comment: @DavidHedlund: Well, the problem is not information off the internet, but information that is relevant to the local situation. But I agree - the answer should point out that vitamin supplements are only required if there is a risk of deficiency. I edited to try and clarify. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Also what is very important to note is diet. Even in area's of vitamin A deficiency the case a) breast feeding, b) formula (which often contain extra vitamins), c) "regular" nutrition are very different.

Comment: Thanks to all for edits! I expanded and clarified the answer in the spirit of your suggestions, as well as "first, do no harm" principle. I also slightly reconciled the edits of @sleske and anongoodnurse in the first part. Deleted my old comments as they are no longer needed.

Comment: Nice edits! +1.

Comment: I agree, +1. I'm still of the opinion that this kind of question is not a good fit for this site, but that's not a criticism of your answer.